# How would I ping IP address produced from script?

Tags: bash, scripts

Scripting novice here.

I have created a script which can show you the ip address of the website which has been entered.

My script:

```
! /bin/bash
echo "Enter web address : "
read address 
echo "Entered web address : $address"
nslookup "$address"
```

Script in use:

```
Enter web address : google.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.206.46
```

How would I then ping the IP address?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using `dig` utility for this purpose.

Here is an example of it's output:

```
dig +short google.com
$ 216.58.206.46
```

Sometimes the result contains multiple addresses, so pip the output to `head` to only get the first one:

```
dig +short address | head -1
```

So you can easily use it in your script without the need of processing the output of `nslookup`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter web address : "
read address 
echo "Entered web address : $address"
nslookup "$address"
ping -c 4 $(dig +short "$address" | head -1)
```

- `$( . . . )` is a [Command substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).
- `ping -c 4` pings the address 4 times
- `+short` is an options to only show the addresses.
- `head -1` returns only first address

Comment: Thanks for all the help with my query. Two more things could you please explain dig and how the command substitution works within the code as I am struggling to understand how command substitution works . Once again thanks for all the help